# Accuracy of the ARM NEON vrsqrteq intrinsic

Tags: floating-point, arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

I am using the ARM NEON `vrsqrteq` intrinsic to calculate the approximate reciprocal square root of a vector of floats. I would like to know the accuracy of that approximation.

However I can't find any documentation that provides this.
The [Neon programmers' guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0018/a/NEON-Intrinsics-Reference/Data-processing/VRSQRTE) simply states that the `vrsqrteq` intrinsic finds the approximate reciprocal square root but does not say a word about the accuracy.

For AVX for example, Intel provides the maximum relative error for the [`_mm256_rsqrt_ps` intrinsic in the Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm256_rsqrt_ps&techs=AVX&ig_expand=5997).

Is there somewhere something similar for ARM NEON intrinsics? I'm guessing the accuracy of the `vrsqrteq` intrinsic is different on different processors, but is there maybe a guaranteed minimal accuracy?

I also have the same situation for the `vrecpeq` intrinsic.

Comment: The precise algorithm is given in the Architecture Reference Manual.  I didn't see error bounds given, but presumably one could derive them.  But the idea seems to be that it is the initial iterate for Newton-Raphson approximation, and you're meant to follow it by iterating `vrsqrts` until you converge to any desired accuracy.

Comment: ARM's Programmer's Guides are informal documentation meant to give you a general overview of the instruction set.  For the full formal details, you are supposed to refer to the Architecture Reference Manual.